# in TFF : How keeping (or saving) the "state" of highest-performing

Tags: tensorflow-federated

in TFF, the variable  `state` is used for evaluation like below :

`test_metrics = evaluation(state.model, federated_test_data)`

So How we can keep this varibale or save it when I find the best one of highest-performing

Answer (score 0):

There are utilities for serializing state in the [tensorflow_federated/python/research/utils/checkpoint_manager.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/utils/checkpoint_manager.py) module. An example of using the `CheckpointManager` can be found in [tensorflow_federated/python/research/utils/training_loop.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/7c5821f85cb2d0379f33bf2b5e02f97d51a16427/tensorflow_federated/python/research/utils/training_loop.py#L76)

The `CheckpointManager` is a fairly thin wrapper around the [`tf.saved_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model) package. Using that directly may be more flexible for your scenario.